# Parsing XML-TEI and transform to Corpus in R

Tags: r, xml, parsing, corpus

I've got three XML-TEI-P5 files I want to transform into a corpus (`stylo`, `quanteda` or `tm` corpus would be best). Since I've never worked with XML I'm having trouble extracting the text and deleting all of the annotations... (and keeping all the special letters like ä, ü, etc.)
This is the furthest I've come so far:

```
library(xml2)
library(XML)
A1 <- read_xml("http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/download_xml/schlegel_athenaeum_1798")
doc1 <- xmlParse(A1)
root1 <- xmlRoot(doc1)
print(root1)
```

And another approach with `stylo` (same document, but saved it locally):

```
Corpus_alle <- load.corpus.and.parse(files = "all", corpus.dir = "TexteXML", markup.type= "XML",
                  corpus.lang = "German", splitting.rule = NULL,
                  sample.size = 10000, sampling = "no.sampling",
                  sample.overlap = 0, number.of.samples = 1,
                  sampling.with.replacement = FALSE, features = "w", 
                  ngram.size = 1, preserve.case = FALSE,
                  encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the package tei2r (https://rdrr.io/github/michaelgavin/tei2r/man/).

I have created this function to load a text corpus into R:

```
read_tei <- function(folder) {
  list.files(folder, pattern = '\\.xml$', full.names = TRUE) %>%
    map_dfr(~.x %>% parseTEI(.,node = "THE_NODE_TO_FIND") %>%tibble())
}

texts <- read_tei("PATH/TO/FILES")
```

To make this function work you have to input the node you are looking for. (Might be text) and you have to specify where your files are located.